# Select para verificar onde uma chave primária é referenciada

Tags: postgresql

Tenho as seguintes tabelas:

_________PESSOA_________

id serial PK

nome varchar(50) NOT NULL

email varchar(100) NOT NULL

tel varchar(14) NOT NULL

---

_________CLIENTE__________

pessoa integer FK/PK --(FK to id in tbl PESSOA)

rg varchar(20) NOT NULL

cpf varchar(14) NOT NULL

---

_________DEPENDENTE________

pessoa integer FK/PK --(FK to id in tbl PESSOA)

fiador integer FK NOT NULL--(FK to pessoa in tbl CLIENTE)

autorizado boolean NOT NULL

---

_________FUNCIONARIO________

pessoa integer FK/PK --(FK to id in tbl PESSOA)

root boolean NOT NULL

---

Uma pessoa pode ser tanto um funcionário como um cliente ou um dependente ou os três.

Quero fazer um select que me informe em quais das três tabelas o ID de PESSOA é usado como chave estrangeira, ou seja, saber um se uma pessoa é um cliente, um cliente/funcionário, um cliente/dependente/funcionario, etc.

A forma de retorno ideal pode ser um array de chars com a leta inicial de cada tabela (ex. {C, D, F}), ou uma string composta pela letra inicial de cada uma 'CDF'.
Eu poderia criar uma coluna `tipo` do tipo `char(1)[]` na tabela `PESSOA` assim toda vez que uma pessoa fosse referenciada em alguma das três tabelas, a tabela pessoa teria o campo `tipo` atualizado, inserindo a letra inicial correspondente a tabela.
Mas se isso puder ser resolvido com um select, acho que seria mais prático.

Comment: Veja se isso resolve seu problema: http://pastebin.com/KhkBW05G

Comment: Não era exatamente isso mas ajudou a achar o caminho. Na verdade eu não preciso que retorne o nome da pessoa, só preciso mesmo da letra. Também preciso fazer essa consulta para uma pessoa específica. Para isso bastou uma clausula `WHERE` no final de cada `JOIN`. Assim, se por exemplo, a pessoa com ID 1, estiver referenciada nas três tabelas (Cliente, Dependente, Funcionario) a consulta retornará três linhas ('C', 'D', 'F'). Já se ela estiver apenas em Cliente e Funcionário, a consulta retornará duas linhas ('C', 'F'). Assim por diante.
Se a pessoa não estiver em nenhuma, o retorno é vazio.

Comment: Se vc quiser da pra fazer com subselect, aí vai retornar uma linha só com 3 colunas

Comment: Como seria com subselect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fazendo `INNER JOIN` apenas os registros que satisfizerem a junção irão aparacer, então você pode conferir o método para seleciona-los da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT pes.nome,
       'C' as tipo
  FROM pessoa pes
  INNER JOIN cliente cli ON cli.pessoa = pes.id
UNION
SELECT pes.nome,
       'D' as tipo
  FROM pessoa pes
  INNER JOIN dependente dep ON dep.pessoa = pes.id
UNION
SELECT pes.nome,
       'F' as tipo
  FROM pessoa pes
  INNER JOIN funcionario fun ON fun.pessoa = pes.id
```

Você pode também escreve-la com `subquery` assim terá 3 colunas de acordo com o tipo de pessoa:

```
SELECT pes.nome,
       (SELECT 1
          FROM cliente cli
         WHERE cli.pessoa = pes.id) as cliente
       (SELECT 1
          FROM dependente dep
         WHERE dep.pessoa = pes.id) as dependente,
       (select 1
          FROM funcionario fun
         WHERE fun.pessoa = pes.id) as funcionario
  FROM pessoa pes
```